# Program F1 key as ^[[A instead of ^[OP in xterm

Tags: bash, keyboard-shortcuts, xterm

I've been given a task to convert our old telnet system to ssh for security reasons. We have little hand held units our employees use that run a telnet connection to the server and runs a curses program.

Problem I've run into is that the weird telnet software they were using before to connect was reading the function keys different from what ssh + xterm is reading them now.

In the curses program that runs, when the user presses <kbd>F1</kbd> it is supposed to send `^[[A` (`1B 5B 5B 41` in hex) and the program reads that and does stuff. However, it's currently receiving `^[OP` (which I think is `1B 5B 4F 50`).

I've found all sorts of things while googling this problem, but none of them seem to be what I need because I don't know what `^[[A` is supposed to be in keysym.

With `inputrc` I've tried

```
^[OP: ^[[A
```

But that just returns an error saying that `^[[A` is an unknown command.

`xmodmap` doesn't seem to help wither because it's looking for a name and I have no idea what that's supposed to be. I also have to do this with <kbd>F2</kbd> to <kbd>F9</kbd> as well.

The environment that I'm using is a really restricted Linux appliance that's running an openbox.

Comment: `\e[A` is what Linux virtual terminals send. `xterm` sends `\e[OP` as it's meant to. Maybe you have `$TERM` incorrectly set to `linux` which makes your program beleive it's interacting with a linux terminal as opposed to an xterm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`xterm` allows you to translate a key into a sequence of characters. This is done by setting resources, for example:

```
XTerm*VT100.Translations: #override\n\
 <Key>F1: string(0x1b) string("[A")\n\
 <Key>F2: string(0x1b) string("[B")\n
```

Normally, you can put these lines in your `~/.Xdefaults` file and it is read by the server at startup. More dynamically, you can load or reload it into the running server with

```
xrdb -merge <~/.Xdefaults
```

Comment: This would be the correct solution, except xrdb segfaults on this system. Thanks.